# HTML Imported font working on local, not on web server

Tags: html, css

I just finished creating the main page of my website, and I've just realized the font I imported from google isn't working. It works and shows up fine when I view the website locally, but as soon as I upload it to my web server it doesn't show. I don't know if it matters, but I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2. Here is the html import:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's the css I have:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300';

body
{
    background-color: #dfdfdf !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif !important;
}
```

It works fine on local, but when I upload to a web server it stops working.

Comment: Press F12 in Google Chrome to open the Developer Tools and see whether there are any error messages in the Console tab. Chrome usually reports when something is wrong with the resources you reference. For instance, check that you open both sites through HTTPS. You may need to reference HTTP version of Google APIs instead.

Comment: I use Opera as my main browser. I loaded chrome however, and under the console tab there are two errors, both 404 failed to load. One if for /js/scripts.js <-- not related to the font at all, and the other is a favicon (doesn't exist). Nothing about fonts. I did notice something strange though. I save my css file, view it locally-it works. When I upload it to me web server and I check the resources on the web page, in the css file the @import is not there and neither is the font-family I specified in the body selector.. why would that code get removed? I keep saving and uploading but nothing.

Comment: I've just noticed none of my css is getting updated on the web server. When I put a new css file in, and inspect element, the latest code I added does not show at all.

Answer (score 1):

Edit* I tried putting all the files on a different domain I own, and it worked perfectly. I checked cloudflare and compared the two domains. They both pointed to my server box, however the one with the issues had an extra a record with * pointing to another ip. I removed it, and it works fine. I don't know what that extra a record was, or why it conflicted with my stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the issue isn't just a caching problem?  The fact that you said you didn't even see your updates in the CSS file when you checked the resources leads me to beleve that it just wasnt getting the newest version

In the future when making any changes to an external style sheet, it's good practice to force a cache refresh by appending a number to the end of your reference URLs, like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css?1">`, and incrementing the number each time.

The `?1` tricks the browser into believing that its a new link, so it re-fetches the stylesheet and gets the latest version.

Comment: I am pretty sure it wasn't, due to the fact that I deleted all the files on the web server. I then uploaded the exact files to the one in question, and another domain I own. The one in question did not update at all, while the other one did. None of my other domains (4-5) had any extra a * record pointing to another ip address, only the one in question. As soon as I removed it, I updated my page and everything worked.

Comment: This example actually strengthens my caching suspicions. Deleting and reuploading the files would not refresh them - the browser has no idea this even happened. The browser is being told to grab the exact same CSS file from the exact same place, and so it will just continue to use the cached version. Uploading it to somewhere new for the first time will of course have the latest changes because it has no previous cache.